# Put some UILabels above each other and react on dynamic sizes in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I'm starting with iPhone programming. I have a `navigationcontroller`, to which I push an new view. For this new view I created a new viewcontroller class with XIB file. in Interface Builder I added some UILabels above each other, showing informations. the content of the uilabels is defined during runtime, the size should be dynamic. right now I do a

```
[label1 sizeToFit];
```

and the dynamic content is shown!

BUT: all labels which were beyond the label1 with the newly added text are now covered by this text. How could I manage them to just move down a bit so that they don't overlap with the label1? Fo I have to do this programmatically?

Comment: Have you considered a table view?

Comment: hmm.. I already use a tableView in the navigation-stack, it seems to me to be used for something with symmetric data. to be concret about my needed view: first is shown a uiimage with 240x240 resolution, then 6 uilabels, the first one has just one line, the second has dynamic content, followed by two static content labels. then a big dynamic content label and finally the last one with static content. there should also follow a uibuttonm after all the labels. my design looks like it wouldn't fit into a tableview..

Comment: Well not necessarily symmetric data. It has been used in skillfully in many apps. I can see your image become a header view, labels in rows (heights of rows can vary and cell layout too ) and your button will come in the footer view. It can be done. Otherwise like you said the layout has to self managed.

Comment: yeah, that sounds interessting.. I think I will give this a try! I will give you feedback if it worked out for me..